# Find the smallest k.

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest $k$, $$\sum_{n = 0}^{1013} \binom{2n}{n}k^n 
\mod{2027} \equiv 0$$

The problem was posted on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/when-does-2027-divide-this-binomial-expression/), but no one has submitted a solution yet. I tried expanding to get an idea, even tried with other primes, but I couldn't get it to work. I am sure, I have missed something. I think it will be much better if someone could post a **hint** instead of a full solution.

Comment: Does this gives some rep there? Is this an open contest?

Comment: this may help; $$\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}^2 ={2n \choose n}$$

Comment: If you want a correct solution / hint, you should at least [quote the question correctly](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/when-does-2027-divide-this-binomial-expression/?group=8cro9OWeqD4d&ref_id=119943).

Comment: @CalvinLin I am sorry, I have corrected the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Evaluate ${ 2n \choose n } \pmod{2027} $, into a form such that you can manipulate the expression using the Binomial Theorem.

More hints are available by clicking through to [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/when-does-2027-divide-this-binomial-expression/?group=8cro9OWeqD4d&ref_id=119943).

Comment: In the binomial theorem the upper index doesn't vary. How do you propose to use the second hint?

Comment: @chubakueno That is a good question. It implies that the form must have a certain shape. You can look at more hints by clicking through to the link and looking at the solution that I added.

Answer (score 2):

Given that
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\right)^2= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}4^n x^n = \frac{1}{1-4x},$$
it is worth to compute $A_k\pmod{2027}$, where:
$$ A_k = (1-4k)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{1013}\binom{2n}{n}k^n\right)^2.$$
It is not so difficult to see that $A_k\equiv(2028-4k)\pmod{2027}$, hence, in order to have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{1013}\binom{2n}{n}k^n\equiv 0\pmod{2027}$$
$k\equiv 507\pmod{2027}$ must hold.
I just posted my solution through squaring on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/when-does-2027-divide-this-binomial-expression/?group=8cro9OWeqD4d), too.

Comment: Very nice. $ \frac{ 1} { \sqrt{1-4x} } $ was the motivation for the problem, and you can see how the coefficients ${2n \choose n}$ are used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the smallest positive integer $k$, Maple says the answer is 1513.

Comment: OP didn't quote the question correctly. See my link.

Comment: My answer was to the question as stated.

Comment: (before the edit)